# Invalid token error in reset password in asp.net 5 rc 1 after moving to new server

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

We are using asp.net 5 rc1 and asp.net Identity, in production level.

After a while we moved to a new server for some reasons. Now our users can't use "forget password" Option! After Filling fields in reset password page, `userManager.ResetPasswordAsync` throws "Invalid Token" Error.

This is `ResetPassword` method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

        var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, model.Code, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(AccountController.ResetPasswordConfirmation), "Account");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
        return View();
    }
```

New users who registered on new server have no problem for using forget password.
I think this problem should be with `ConcurrencyStamp` or `SecurityStamp` properties of user. maybe they aren't valid on new machine.

Any Idea?

Comment: You say you're on a new server. Are you still also running the old server and load balancing? Or were the tokens generated on the previous machine?

Comment: @blowdart Old server stopped. We are running only on new server

Comment: Do you have `machineKey` in your web.config?

Comment: @trailmax No we haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed right. Problem was from `SecurityStamp`. I Updated All SecurityStamps by `UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync` and now old users can also using forget password without any problem.